# 7-Zip: Getting Extraction Failed "Unsupported Method" when trying to self-extract and run setup.exe for a 7-zip file that has a password

Tags: 7-zip, self-extracting

I am creating the zip file using the 7-Zip "Add to Archive" window.  Name is ccc.7z with a password specified.  All other options use the default.

I run the DOS command: copy /b 7zSD.sfx + config.txt + ccc.7z ccc.exe

I am launching ccc.exe and I want the user to have to specify the password that is in the archive.

My config.txt contents are:

- ;!@Install@!UTF-8!
- Title="ccc Installation"
- Progress="yes"
- GUIFlags=""
- OverwriteMode="0"
- InstallPath="%TEMP%"
- ExtractTitle="Extracting"
- ExtractDialogText=""
- ExtractCancelText="Abort"
- BeginPrompt="Do you want to install ccc?"
- RunProgram="setup.exe"
- ;!@InstallEnd@!

The message in Extraction Failed window is "Unsupported Method".  If i remove the password from the archive, the extraction works without error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the same issue when create *.7z file using LZMA2. LZMA2 is not supported by SFX tool. It works fine for me after I changed LZMA2 to LZMA